# Matlab Linprog , The equality constraints are not consistent

Tags: matlab, linear-programming

I am used linprog matlab command to solve a wind-hydro generation problem in a published article, that have equality and inequality constrains. after each running there is not same result and show: "Exiting: The primal is infeasible; the equality constraints are dependent but not consistent". please help me to get acceptable result.

Comment: If the paper shows an optimal solution x then there is a somewhat painless way to debug this. Evaluate A * x and compare to b (similar for Aeq * x and beq). As the optimal solution is feasible, any infeasibilities pinpoint errors in your equations.

Answer (score 1):

Equality constraints are, naturally, quite "hard" constraints w.r.t. inequality constraints. Given your error message, it'a probable that your inequality constraints can *never all be satisfied simultaneously*, which means that your solution space; set of candidate solutions, is zero. Hence, your program is infeasible for all possible decision variable values, and hence infeasible itself.

Take an extra look on how you've implemented your equality constraints, and see if they, on first glance, describe some "impossible co-relation". If you don't find the problem yourself, please post more details on your linear program as well as your implementation of it, and I shall likewise edit this answer with more details.